# Expanding an external node to internal node in AVLTree

Tags: java, avl-tree

I am doing this AVLTree assignment and I have an issue with the insert method. I am getting an error when it gets to z.resetHeight();

```
    public void insert(K key, V value) {

    AVLnode<K, V> hold = TreeSearch(key, root);
    AVLnode<K, V> z = hold;
    DictEntry<K, V> temp = new DictEntry<K, V>(key, value);
    z.setEntry(temp);

    while (z != null) {
        z.resetHeight();
        if (java.lang.Math
                .abs(z.left().getHeight() - z.right().getHeight()) > 1) {
            z = triNodeRestructure(z.parent().parent(), z.parent(), z);
            z.left().resetHeight();
            z.right().resetHeight();
            z.resetHeight();
            break;
        }
        size++;
        z = z.parent();
    }

}
```

resetHeight is from a class AVLnode which I am not allowed to modify as specified in the assignment.

```
public class AVLnode<K,V> implements Position<K,V> {
private AVLnode<K,V> parent;          // reference to the parent node
private AVLnode<K,V> left;            // reference to the left child
private AVLnode<K,V> right;           // reference to the right child
private DictEntry<K,V> entry;         // reference to the entry stored at the node
private int height;                   // height of the node for checking balance-height property

public AVLnode(DictEntry<K,V> inputEntry, AVLnode<K,V>  inputParent, AVLnode<K,V>  inputLeft, AVLnode<K,V>  inputRight)
{
    entry  = inputEntry;
    parent = inputParent;
    left   = inputLeft;
    right  = inputRight;
    height = 0;
    if (left != null ) height  = Math.max(height,1+left.getHeight());
    if (right != null ) height = Math.max(height,1+right.getHeight()); 
}

public AVLnode<K,V>  parent(){ return parent;}
public AVLnode<K,V>  left() {return left;}
public AVLnode<K,V>  right() {return right;}
public int getHeight () { return height; }
public DictEntry<K,V> getEntry() { return entry; } 
public void setParent(AVLnode<K,V>  newParent){ parent = newParent; }
public void setLeft(AVLnode<K,V>  newLeft) {left = newLeft;}
public void setRight(AVLnode<K,V>  newRight) { right = newRight; }  
public void setEntry(DictEntry<K,V> newEntry) { entry = newEntry; }
public DictEntry<K,V> element(){return entry;}

public void resetHeight() throws AVLTreeException{
if ( left == null || right == null ) throw  new AVLTreeException("Attempt to update height for external node ");
height = 1+Math.max(left.getHeight(),right.getHeight());
}
```

}

I think the issue is that when I use my insert method I haven't yet set a left or right child. So getHeight throws an exception because both children of the node I am inserting are null. I'm not quite sure how to implement this. I have tried creating new nodes to set as hold's left and right child but I don't know what I should put as the parameters without messing up the list except for null, but that just puts me back to where I Was.

Comment: Shouldn't you begin the `resetHeight()` loop from `z.parent()` rather than `z`?

Comment: do you mean the `while( z != null)` loop? I tried to follow the teachers pseudo code so I think that should be correct. I'll try it though

Comment: The loop looks correct, but you can't begin it at the node you've added because it has no children, and you don't need to because the node you've added can't need its height to be reset anyway. So I'm suggesting you begin it at the new node's parent as I've shown in my answer below.

Comment: yeah, you were right, it got rid of my exception, thanks!

Comment: Cool. Do you want to accept my answer so everyone knows its done? - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As `z` doesn't have any children and so can't be unbalanced, begin the `resetHeight()` loop from `z`'s parent:

```
z.setEntry(temp);

z = z.parent();
while (z != null) {
        z.resetHeight();
        // etc...
```